# Transient shaping of kicks and snare drums

Tags: sound-design, transients

I use compressor to get that transient for my kicks, snares...but think it as real..
  A drummer hitting kick or snare.,,if the bpm of song is low then the transient will be less powerful as compared to song having bpm greater than that...
 Because as a bpm is fast, the speed of drummer's hand will be more...and hence transient will be more powerful...
So how get that in my DAW?

Comment: Actually, the sound of the drums on their own isn't really changed by how fast the song is. One thing that does interact with tempo is any compressors used on the drums will interact with both the decay time of the drums and the next drum hit, so if the drum is hit again before the first sound decays, then it will sound different from how it sounds when the drum has fully decayed before it is it, and likewise with the decay time setting on the compressor.

Comment: @ToddWilcox thanks for your reply....but I'm just wondering how to get that sound right...when drum is hit harder and when drum is hit with low force....is there any method to do that?

Comment: If you have midi drums, velocity can help, otherwise use a transient shaper and not a compressor